# Joining selected column to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am try running this query and it takes long time because of the join i am using

```
SELECT T1.Id,T2.T2Id,T2.Col2
FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 Id, TT.T2Id,TT.Col2
                    FROM Table2 TT
                    WHERE TT.TypeId=3
                    ORDER BY TT.OrderId
                    )AS T2 ON T2 .Id=T1.Id
```

Thing is it doesn't let me do something like `TT.Id=T1.Id` with in the join query.

Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: why it doesn't let you do something like TT.Id=T1.Id, what does it say

Comment: Is there some reason for you to use TOP 1? You simply wanna join the tables?

Comment: @Fnightangel: Yes, just need top 1 based on type 3

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida: Problem is it doesn't let you!!!

Comment: you need any record based on type 3? because you didn't use order by.
can you post what data do you expect to get?

Comment: What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: Does this question needs a downvote??

Comment: @Zane: can you please explain?

Comment: Well I didn't downvote but it seems like a silly question. Example why would you want a TOP 1 in this manner. The result returned could be completely random.

Comment: @Zane: Ops... i just put a sample code here (with fake table names etc...) actually I do order by the order id on the table. Will update the question!

Comment: @Fnightangel: Yes, I am using the order by. Forgot to include in sample query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with `outer apply`:

```
SELECT T1.Id, T2.T2Id, T2.Col2
FROM Table1 T1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 T2Id, T2.Col2
             FROM Table2 TT
             WHERE TT.TypeId = 3 AND TT.Id = T1.Id) T2
```

Comment: `Left outer join` may require `Outer apply`

Comment: Brilliant!! I never used cross apply before

Comment: @huMptyduMpty MilenPavlov have true that `left outer join` require `outer apply`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.Id, T2.T2Id, T2.Col2
FROM Table1 T1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 T2Id, T2.Col2
             FROM Table2 TT
             WHERE TT.TypeId = 3 AND T1.Id = TT.Id
             Order by  T2id desc) T2
```

I would use `Outer Apply` and `T1.Id = TT.Id` in the where condition since T1 is the parent table plus adding on order by - if needed for ordered result set

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all your derived table will produce non deterministic results, as the top 1 row you return may differ each time you run it, even if the data in the table remains the same.  You could put an order by clause in the the derived table to prevent that.

Is there an index on Table1.id? What exactly are you trying to achieve though, is it to return all rows from Table1, with just one row of many from Table2 that has the same ID?

If so I would look into using Cross Apply instead.  Or maybe in this case Outer Apply.  If I get a chance later I'll write up an example if needed, but in the mean time just Google Outer Apply for SQL Server.

Dan